# ¿Cómo puedo activar un emulador para flutter?

Tags: flutter, vscode

Tengo un problema con flutter, al iniciar el proyecto en vscode, se abre automáticamente el navegador edge y quiero activar un emulador como el de android studio, tengo instalado el android studio pero quiero trabajar con vscode ya que se me hace menos pesado.
Dejo la foto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para trabajar con un emulador puedes instalarlo desde **Android studio** una ves instalado lo ejecutas por lo menos 1 ves, para comprobar que este funcionando.

### Pasos para la instalación del emulador, pasos directos de la [documentación](https://esflutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#configurar-el-emulador-de-android).

1. Habilita [VM acceleration](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration) en tu equipo.
2. Abra **Android Studio>Tools>Android>AVD** Manager y selecciona **Create Virtual Device**. (El submenú **Android** está presente solo cuando se encuentra dentro de un proyecto de Android.)
3. Elija un dispositivo y seleccione **Next**.
4. Selecciona una o más imágenes del sistema que quieres emular, y selecciona **Next**. Una imagen x86 o x86_64 es recomendada.
5. Dentro de Emulated Performance, selecciona **Hardware - GLES 2.0** para habilitarlo [aceleración de hardware](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration).
6. Verifica que la configuración de AVD es correcta, y selecciona Finish.
7. Para mayor detalle de los pasos de arriba, vea [Administrando AVDs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html).
   En el Administrador de Dispositivos Virtuales de Android (AVD), da clic en la barra de herramienta **Run**. El emulador iniciará el arranque y mostrara el lienzo (canvas) por defecto para la versión del SO y dispositivo seleccionado.